# RC debounce mosfet gate

Tags: mosfet, remote-control, debounce

I am trying to debounce a switch that controls the gate of a mosfet.
Will the circuit below work, or do I need to re-arrange some of the parts?

*The circle thing should have been drawn as a mosfet.

[image]

Comment: Actually the "circle thing" is a bipolar junction transistor (BJT) and not a MOSFET.

Comment: The wire going in goes to the gate pin

Comment: Can you share MOSFET and switch datasheet? Can you also show the other connection to output pin? Currently it's floating

Comment: I don't know the exact specifications of the mosfet since this will be a modification to an existing circuit I have not yet bought. The voltage applied to the gate is around 12V and the mosfet is used to handle 12V and around 20A going into a motor.

Answer (score 3):

For ordinary debounce, you want

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9mPiL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your circuit will leave the gate floating when the switch is open, and that is technically called A Bad Thing.

Switch bounce usually lasts a few milliseconds. In the circuit I've shown, the 100 ohm resistor is intended to protect the switch from the current surge you get if you just short out a capacitor. For a beefy switch it may not be necessary.

I've shown a 10 volt supply, and something like 10 to 12 volts is generally a good idea for driving MOSFETs. If you're using logic-level FETs you can get by with less, and you can even use less on regular FETs, but you may get inconsistent results. For instance, if your logic circuits are running on 3.3 volts, you may be tempted to use that, but a lot of power MOSFETs are not guaranteed to work with less than 4 volts on the gate. Know your parts before you build your circuit. "Good judgment comes from experience. Experience comes from bad judgment."

Also, learn to use the schematic entry tool which is part of this site. It's the seventh icon from the left above the answer text window.

Comment: So in my circuit I should move the resistor just before the gate pin of the mosfet? The voltage will be 12-13 volts and the mosfet controls a motor. The R3 resistor serves so as to protect the gate from overvoltage?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YhcCw.png Should I do it like this? Also, the capacitor will charge and discharge in t = R*C = 3.3ms, correct

Comment: "I should move the resistor just before the gate pin of the mosfet?" No. Your circuit won't work. "The R3 resistor serves so as to protect the gate from overvoltage?" Nope. When the switch is open, R3 pulls the gate up to the high drive voltage. When the switch is closed, R4 pulls the gate down to nearly zero.

Comment: "Should I do it like this?" No. Depending on the switch, you may cause it to stop working reliably. When the switch is closed you'll get a large current spike as the capacitor is charged virtually instantaneously, and for low-level switches this can burn them out over time. Then, when the switch opens, there is no discharge path to cause the capacitor/gate voltage to return to zero, so the FET will never (well, almost never) turn off.

Comment: Ok, so if I have understood correctly: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QAAup.png The capacitor will charge through R2, and thus not instantly and then it will discharge through R1 while providing voltage for the gate. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that will do what you want. And the time constant is 3.3 msec.